# Why isn't pylint in venv with vscode responding to settings?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pylint

G'day!

I'm trying to get `pylint` working with Visual Studio Code in a python venv, but I'm having difficulties. I think I've read more or less every question and blog post on the web about this, but I'm still unable to solve it. I must be missing something vital …

I'm using VS Code version 1.32.3 on macOS 10.14.3 with a virtual environment with python 2.7.10 (default macOS `python` version). Code works just fine with the venv (relevant imports works and all that) but the linter only reacts to runtime breaking errors (as I think is default).
I have however set the following settings:

```
    "python.linting.pylintUseMinimalCheckers": false,
    "python.linting.enabled": true,
    "python.linting.lintOnSave": true,
    "python.linting.pylintEnabled": true
```

I'm not getting any errors anywhere.

Linting in itself seems to be working, but not catching all the issues I'd like. Creating a .pylintrc file with `enable=all` has no effect, setting `"python.linting.pylintArgs": ["--enable=all"]` has no effect.

Running the linter both from the terminal from inside Code and from Terminal.app both render the full list of (cosmetic) errors, either with just `pylint` or the absolute path to the linter inside the venv.

I've also tried supplying both a relative and absolute path to pylint inside the venv for the `"python.linting.pylintPath"` setting, which also has no effect.

As a last resort I earlier today cleaned out all of `~/Library/Application Support/Code` and `~/.vscode` and reinstalled the app, but that didn't have any effect either.

What need I do to get Code to list *all* issues?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1):

Use flake8 instead.flake8 works well in vscode for me. I have also faced errors in vscode with pylint and wasted time in resolving them but only flake8 saved me.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!
I tried switching to `flake8` but I'm not getting any feedback from that either (unless it's a major coding error), so I think this is a combined vscode & linter problem, not the linter itself, since they also work on the command line.

Comment: yup may be. Assuming you are using right interpreter (python 2.7) and installed flake8 extension above that version. If not you can select different interpreter in vscode and then try installing flake8 on that.